# Renaming file before saving in ActiveStorage - Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to rename a user uploaded file before saving in ActiveStorage and I don't seem to find any docs to do that. Hopefully someone has successfully done it and has code examples to share.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following method

```
@message.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file.pdf')
```

in the official [ActiveStorage](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects) documentation you can find more examples

Answer (score 2):

This method in the model works for me:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
has_one_attached :anything

  before_save do
    if self.anything.attached?
        ext = '.' + self.anything.blob.filename.extension
        self.anything.blob.update(filename: 'desired_file_name' + ext)
    end
  end
end
```